# How does the camel, the lion and the child apply to everyday life?

Tags: nietzsche

Having read several interpretations (noted below) of Nietzsche's Three Metamorphoses, how does this apply to everyday life? How do you apply it? When do you know you have metamorphosized?

**Sources**

http://members.core.com/~ascensus/docs/Metamor.html
http://nietzschespirit.blogspot.com/2008/07/camel-lion-and-baby.html
http://www.highexistence.com/friedrich-nietzsches-guide-to-conquering-your-existence/

Comment: What exactly are you hoping for someone here to explain to you; what does an answer to this look like in your mind? What hypotheses have you formed and what has your research uncovered so far?

Comment: @Joseph Weissman - If i had an answer in my mind, i would not be asking the question of its application in everyday life. If i had a hypotheses, i would be forming a question based on it. The question stems from not understanding its application in everyday life. How do you apply it? In conversations? In interactions? If so how? How does one know if metamorphosis has taken place or is that no longer a question?

Comment: It would help if those downvoting provided a sense of why the question requires a downvote. Ask before downvoting. If not you have formed a conception of thought without understanding where the question stems from.

Comment: i don't think it's meant to apply to everyday life

Comment: but i voted "up" even though i think it's based on a mistake, on the grounds that there's tonnes worse mistakes evident on here than getting a little familiar with nietzsche. peace.

Comment: i will give u an answer to ur question padwan :D  ... play, play at greatness :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nietzsche is discussing, **let's suppose**, the stages higher men have undergone through the course of history. So trying to apply it to everyday life would depend on one being a "higher man", and higher men are better off **let's say** forming their own values not drawing from Nietzsche.

In effect, it's just "philosophy", a way to convince us something, the nature of the "overman". I wouldn't apply it to anything other than the history of philosophy.

I am not saying you're the herd, as many scholars would deny that is an objective category. I'm just saying that Nietzsche isn't writing a guide book on going over. You would be better off with an eastern religion, or kung fu, or maybe even socializing with the upper classes, if you want to better yourself.

Oh I added some qualifications, but even if N.'s writing are meant to be transformative, they are meant I think to prepare the earth for the overman, perhaps by helping us love humanity. There's probably something like this is the self help literature if your question is a burning one... which of course is possible, many of us feel upset at the defacement of higher values, and despise a society in which the last man can thrive. But if you want to go a step further and become what you are, then I would suggest living and thinking like Nietzsche, not living out his philosophy.

Indeed, at the close Zarathustra / Nitezsche cajoles his friends the higher men to go their own way and not be followers or believers in him. You might want to raad ecce homo for something more in the spirit of self help. Oh and fwiw I wouldn't wipe my arse with those links, for whatever reason.